# how to store N-triple rdf in triple store and querying SPARQl

Tags: rdf

I am trying to try out storing N-triple and querying them. What is the simplest way to store N-triple in triple store or rather the simplest server do that.

I would highly appreciate help in this.

Answer (score 2):

Try Apache Jena, and its [TDB database](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader):

```
$ tdbloader --loc mystore file.nt
$ tdbquery --loc mystore "select * {?s ?p ?o}" # direct query
$ tdbquery --loc mystore --query myquery.sparql # from a file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/) if you would prefer using a *web based query form* or the ability to *query your data like any SPARQL endpoint* via **http**.

For more details see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907450/1413297) on this question: [Where do I test my queries for my RDF written in SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13897712/1413297)